# C# Simulation Closing

Tags: c#

I just finished my little 2 Person game, but as soon as i finish to enter the 2 colours it just closes on the next Key pressed. I don't find an error, maybe someone can help me? Or also just tell me how to improve my code. I only recently started programming with C# and am thankful for help

My Programm Code is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Fahrrad
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Geben sie die Farbe 'blau' oder 'gruen' ein: ");
            Velo Velo1 = new Velo(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Geben sie die andere Farbe ein: ");
            Velo Velo2 = new Velo(Console.ReadLine());

            ConsoleKeyInfo input;

            input = Console.ReadKey();

            switch(input.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    Velo2.Gangwechsel(1);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    Velo2.Gangwechsel(0);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    Velo2.Bremse(true);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    Velo2.Fortbewegung(true);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.W:
                    Velo1.Gangwechsel(1);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.S:
                    Velo1.Gangwechsel(0);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.A:
                    Velo1.Bremse(true);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D:
                    Velo1.Fortbewegung(true);
                    break;
            }
        
        }
    }
}
```

And my Class Code is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Fahrrad
{
    internal class Velo
    {
        private double gaenge;
        private bool bremse;
        private string farbe;
        private double maxGang;
        private bool fahrend;

        // Konstruktor
        public Velo(string farbe)
        {
            this.gaenge = 1;
            this.farbe = farbe;
            if(farbe == "blau")
            {
                maxGang = 7;
            }
            else if (farbe == "gruen")
            {
                maxGang = 3;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Falsche eingabe");
                Console.ReadKey();
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }

        public void Gangwechsel(double schalten)
        {
            if(schalten == 0)
            {
                this.gaenge--;

                if(this.gaenge == 0 && this.fahrend == true)
                {
                    this.gaenge = 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Sie sind bereits im tiefsten gang");
                }
            }
            else if(schalten == 1 && this.fahrend == true)
            {
                this.gaenge++;

                if(this.gaenge > this.maxGang)
                {
                    this.gaenge = this.maxGang;
                    Console.WriteLine("Sie sind bereits im höchsten Gang");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sie müssen zum Gang wechseln fahren");
            }

             Console.WriteLine("Sie sind momentan im " + this.gaenge + " gang");
        }
    
        public void Bremse(bool bremse)
        {
            this.bremse = bremse;
        
            if(fahrend == true && this.bremse == true)
            {
                fahrend= false;
                Console.WriteLine("Sie haben die Fahrt beendet");
            }
        }

        public void Fortbewegung(bool fahrend)
        {
            this.fahrend = fahrend;
        
            if(this.bremse == true && this.fahrend == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sie haben die Bremse noch angezogen");
                this.fahrend = false;
            }
            else
            { 
                this.fahrend = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Das " + this.farbe + "Fahrrad ist im" + this.gaenge + " Gang losgefahren");
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never _repeat_ the choice; a simple loop will do fine.

Comment: You need to tell the console to read the next keyboard input, otherwise it thinks it's finished

Comment: Any game or simulation needs a game _loop_. Create an outer loop where actions are repeated as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a game loop that can be terminated by a key.
For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Geben sie die Farbe 'blau' oder 'gruen' ein: ");
    Velo Velo1 = new Velo(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Geben sie die andere Farbe ein: ");
    Velo Velo2 = new Velo(Console.ReadLine());

    ConsoleKeyInfo input;
    bool gameIsRunning = true;

    while(gameIsRunning)
    {
        input = Console.ReadKey();

        switch(input.Key)
        {
            // your other rules here
            case ConsoleKey.Q:
                gameIsRunning = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    
}
```